# Changing the delegate to whichever screen is viewed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, notifications

I've read in other posts that having multiple delegates in iOS is not the right way of doing things (and perhaps not even possible?), and instead you should be using things such as NSNotifications to alert other (multiple) View Controllers of events.

Is it better practice to keep an object's delegate the same throughout the runtime of the app, or is it useful to change the delegate to whichever VC is modal at any given time.

Here's an example:
I have some simulator class that's running in the background and generating random numbers that will be used by several different view controllers in the application.  Since only one VC can be viewable at a time, I could just make the active VC the delegate of the simulator, and switch the delegate every time the UI changes.

...or I can use Notifications like I am doing now, and have the VC register for notifications upon loading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In purpose, a delegate is an object that does some work on behalf of some other object.  What you seem to have is a situation where various objects are clients of a data provider.  There's no sense in what you've described that the background task is in charge of accomplishing something that the view controllers are just helping out with.

To make the implementation fit the structure, I'd suggest either assigning the background object as a "data provider" property for the view controllers or staying with notifications...depending on what degree of coupling you prefer and which class you have initiating the data transfer.